# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project.app' while trying to add foreignkey constraint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, modulenotfounderror

Here is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class CategoryList(models.Model):
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Cat_Img = models.ImageField(upload_to='cat_media')
    Active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class ImgDetails(models.Model):
    Img = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    Category = models.ForeignKey(CategoryList, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, null=False)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    UserDetail = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    Valid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    UploadDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I'm trying to add a foreign-key constraint on `ImgDetails` with `CategoryList`. It is throwing error

```
   from cam_project.cam_app.models import CategoryList
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cam_project.cam_app'
```

I tried importing `from cam_project.cam_app.models import CategoryList` but still no progress. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: where is the file in which you are importing it?, show that and also your directory structure

Comment: see i'm using foreignkey constraint within the same models . it is working fine when i'm creating foreign key constraint with user as you can see in ImgDetails but not with CategoryList. i don't  think there is any need of directory structure as both my classes are within the same models.py of a single app

Answer (score 0):

If your `models.py` is in the `cam_app` you can just use:

```
from .models import CategoryList
```

or if you are importing another app's models.py, you should specify the app name as well:

```
from .app.models import Model
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the directory that contains `cam_project` must be in the PYTHONPATH.

You can check it inspecting  `sys.path`.

To add it you can:

`export PYTHONPATH=<YOUR_DIR>:$PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the error is in `models.py`. Your foreign-key constraint is working fine. It seems you are importing `CategoryList` in some other file(my best guess `views.py`) In django absolute import are relative to your `manage.py`. So I think you import should be

```
from cam_app.models import CategoryList
```